# How does indexer inheritance work in generics?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dictionary, indexer

Suppose we have the following scenario: a class that derives from Dictionary and this class also has an implementation for a string indexer, but the property by which the indexer returns the value is not the key (think of it like a dictionary of elements that have an int or a guid as key, but also have a string property for which you wish to make an indexer).

```
public class StringDictionary<TKey> :
    Dictionary<TKey, object>
{
    public object this[string val]
    { get { } set { } }
}
```

Now, here is how C# behaves (which is fairly intuitive), depending which type TKey has when you instantiate StringDictionary

```
StringDictionary<string> dict1;
dict1["string"]; // will use the indexer defined in StringDictionary

StringDictionary<int> dict2;
dict2[0]; // will use the indexer defined in Dictionary
dict2["string"]; // will use the indexer defined in StringDictionary
```

- if TKey is string, only the indexer declared in the StringDictionary will be available
- if TKey is something other than string, both indexers are available (the string indexer in StringDictionary and the TKey indexer in Dictionary)

My question is: how does C# decides which indexer to use when there is a 'conflict' between the indexer defined in the generic base class and the one defined in the derived class, like in the example above? Is it the same as if TKey was declared explicitly as string and the new indexer simply hides the inherited one?

As I've said, it's pretty intuitive, it doesn't throw any errors or warnings, but I want to know the mechanism by which this works, because it seems to me like this is a trickier version of member hiding.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I don't usually do that. Thanks for the advice and for the edit.

Comment: More of a guess than an authoritative answer: indexers are essentially properties, and properties are essentially a pair of methods, so it uses plain old method overloading. (Ignoring metadata that lets you get the properties of a class by reflection etc.) The indexer calls should compile to `dict.get_Item(0)` and `dict.get_Item("string")`, and it's legal to overload these methods on parameter types. A decompiler ([dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or such) should corroborate this.

Comment: You are *overloading* the indexer.  The compiler picks the appropriate one based on the indexer argument.  I'd say you'll have pretty significant problems actually writing the getter in a meaningful way so a `StringDictionary<SomeType>` could work.  Best to not do this at all.

Comment: @HansPassant When TKey is string, it is still considered overloading? Because the signatures are the same. Writing the getter is not a problem, at least for my case. But I agree that it could cause confusion.

Comment: Well, it takes the indexer from the class you are using `StringDictionary`. If you want the original index, you will have to take `((Dictionary<string, object>)dict1)["string"]`

Comment: No, when TKey is string then your version of the indexer *shadows* the inherited one.  Which is why it looks like it has only one indexer.  That normally generates a warning that you suppress with the *new* keyword but not in the case of generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Shadowing

Suppose we have this base class

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now suppose we derive from it and for some reason, we want to have a name property that behaves differently:

```
public class DerivedClass
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Always the same"; }
        set { throw new Exception(); }
    }
}
```

The C# compiler will complain that we cannot do this, the class already has a `Name` property!  What we can do, is tell the C# compiler that when we're using `DerivedClass` we want to use our `Name` property.  We do this by adding the `new` property to the `Name` property in `DerivedClass`:

```
public new string Name
```

This is called shadowing

#### Side-Effects

When you use `DerivedClass` as a type of `DerivedClass` everything behaves as you'd expected it:

```
DerivedClass derived = new DerivedClass();
derived.Name = "Joe";   // Exception
```

But if you attempt to use `Name` by using the base class, you're really using the `BaseClass` implementation:

```
BaseClass base = derived;
base.Name = "Joe";      // No Exception
```

There is no way to prevent this.

### Back to the Question

When using generics, you don't mark the indexer as `new` because it's not always a `new` method (it is only when TKey is a `string`), but when it needs to be, it is implicitly `new`.  Thus, in those cases, the C# compiler will use the version of the method/indexer that that it knows about.

In the case of using it as a `StringDictionary<string>`, it'll use your custom implementation.  It the case of using it as a `Dictionary<string, string>`, it'll use the `Dictionary<string,string>` implementation of the indexer.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. Essentially what's happening is just implicit shadowing.